# What is the XPath query to pull a series of elements, including the element "wrapper" tags?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to pull the list of nodes contained in the following example XML document example, including the Element tag but not the payload tags.

```
<ABCCo>
    <cfg appID="Sample" svcID="SampleService" svcVer="2.0"/>
    <payload>
        <Element>
            <Data1>1000611598</Data1>
            <Data2>381</Data2>
        </Element>
        <Element>
            <Data1>1000611606</Data1>
            <Data2>381</Data2>
        </Element>
    </payload>
</ABCCo>
```

Everything I've tried so far returns the contents of the Element (Data1, Data2, etc.) but not the surrounding Element and /Element. I tried about 20 different approaches with no luck -- this shouldn't be that difficult, but I need an answer and ran out of time to keep trying different approaches. So what I need is the contents of the payload as separate nodes, but still including the Element tags, like so:

```
(Node0)
<Element>
    <Data1>1000611598</Data1>
    <Data2>381</Data2>
</Element>

(Node1)
<Element>
    <Data1>1000611606</Data1>
    <Data2>381</Data2>
</Element>
```

The following line of code yields only one single node:

```
var nodes = passThruXml.SelectNodes("//ABCCo/payload");
```

```
<Element>
    <Data1>1000611598</Data1>
    <Data2>381</Data2>
</Element>
<Element>
    <Data1>1000611606</Data1>
    <Data2>381</Data2>
</Element>
```

Everything is there, but as one single node. If I try to get the inner nodes using this:

```
var nodes = passThruXml.SelectNodes("//ABCCo/payload/Element");
```

I get a list containing 2 nodes, but they are missing the Element tag:

```
<Data1>1000611598</Data1>
<Data2>381</Data2>

<Data1>1000611606</Data1>
<Data2>381</Data2>
```

I did get the code to work using the first approach and then using string parsing to separate the result out into separate nodes, but I don't like that -- there should be a way to do this using XPath...

Ideas? Thanks for any feedback

Comment: I did get this to work by using string operations to parse out the nodes from the result of using //ABCCo/payload, but there should be a way to do it using XPath...

Comment: Do you want extraction or transform? Your input does not have `E*` tags but your output xml does.

Comment: Ugh, good point. Edited so those are correct now.

Comment: Don't really understand how `//ABCCo/payload/Element` doesn't work given the example XML provided.  Perhaps provide a little more detail about how you're invoking the XPath expression.

Comment: @DavidDenenberg I added a couple of code snippets to show what I mean. I did try maybe a dozen other approaches but never succeeded in getting what I was after.